# response 413 Request Header Fields Too large

Tags: node.js, http, request, nodemailer

I am using Node to send emails through our mail server,  I have encountered a 431 Header Fields too large a couple times.  One thing to note, is I wrote a quick and dirty mailer using node and the nodemailer package, and the request I send is using a GET instead of a post, and all the email info is in the request.  Would I be better off using a POST for something like this, or would I run into the same problem if the header is already too large? Ive seen some answered questions regarding this, but nothing on the GEt VS POST part.

Thanks in advance.